# jQuery slidedown problem

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery slidedown menu in unordered list - although it worked on Firefox, I only realised there was a problem when someone told me they were having problem displaying it properly in IE. The menu jack-knifes where the jquery is inserted in the list :(

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="Item.html">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Third</a></li>
    <li id="flip_1"><span>Family</span></li>
        <div id="panel_1">
            <li><a href="">Child 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Child 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Child 3</a></li>
        </div>

    <li><a href="history">History</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Not only is this menu breaking, the jquery item jerks back into place when clicked.

Here's the code for the slide:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#flip_1").click(function(){
      $("#panel_1").slideToggle("slow");
    }); 
 });
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Helen... just a Q. Do you have many of this `#flip_N` and `#panel_N` elements?

Comment: @roXon - Yes, I have 3 altogether. But I disable them all except one and to help debug the problem and it that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is invalid. So you will get unexpected results. You have a list item that contains a div and then more list items. List items must go inside `ol` or `ul` tags. Fix that first and let us know what happens.

```
 <div id="panel_1">
        <!-- These are supposed to be inside a ul or ol tag -->
        <li><a href="">Child 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Child 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Child 3</a></li>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm waiting for my friend to get home and test it for me on his computer. I don't use Windows computer and can't test it now. But I have included the <ul> tag.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Although that worked,it created another problem - space between the sub-menu and the other menu beneath it. That's the reason I removed the <ul> tag in the first place :(

Comment: It is probably just a padding/margin error. Try adding `ul {padding: 0; margin: 0; }` to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Agree.
All should be something like

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="Item.html">First</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Second</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Third</a></li>
   <li id="flip_1"><span>Family</span></li>
   <div id="panel_1">
   <ul >

           <li><a href="">Child 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Child 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Child 3</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <li><a href="history">History</a></li>
</ul>


   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#flip_1").click(function(){
     $("#panel_1").slideToggle("slow");
   }); 
});

</script>
```

And even ie6(!) will get it.